# Differentiable at $0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a function defined on the reals that satisfies $|f(x) − f(y)| \le |x − y|^2$ for all $x$ and $y$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at all points $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Can you calculate $f''(0)$?

I understand the basic definitions and that we must show that the function is continuous on the neighborhood and that the limit exists. However, I do not understand how to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your assumption as

$$-(x - y)^2 \leq f(x) - f(y) \leq (x - y)^2.$$

We assume that $x > y$. Then it follows

$$ - (x - y) \leq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \leq x - y.$$

When you take the limit and also have a look at the case $y > x$, you can easily see $f'(y) = 0$ for all $y$, i. e., $f$ is differentiable. I think you can now answer the second question concerning $f''(0)$.

Comment: First, should those be absolute values or parenthesis? Also, does this still comply with the Epsilon and Delta argument? I thought that we would have to let delta be something and show the limit of the middle term is less than epsilon.

Comment: @lj_growl This are parentheses. Note the following: If $a,x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\vert x \vert \leq a$, then we have $-a \leq x \leq a$. For the second question: It's just the definition of the differential quotient: $f'(y) = \lim_{x \to y} \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the definition of a differentiable function - show that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists.

Given some arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}$, let us evaluate the required limit (denoting $x+h=y)$:

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\leq|x-y|=|h|$, and so if we take the limit $h\rightarrow 0$, we get that the limit above is also $0$. This means that $f$ is differentiable anywhere, and that its derivative is always $0$. This also means that the second derivative of $f$ is also always $0$.

Comment: It seems to me that both proofs are two sides of the same coin - one uses the definition of a differentiable function to conclude that the function is differentiable and of derivative 0 (and hence constant), the other finds that the function is constant and hence of derivative 0 (and of course differentiable).

Comment: Although I do like the generalization you made